# ¿Llamar un ARREGLO lleno de una clase en otra clase diferente y usarlo en un ciclo FOR e IF?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, método, objeto

Como puedo mandar a llamar un arreglo con valores a otra clase, recorrerlo (con un for) y validar cada indice (con un if) para mandar un mensaje si es que esta completo o de lo contrario mandar un mensaje de error.Osea un metodo en la clase Validaciones que resiva el objeto del main
Tal ves sean cosas sencillas o triviales pero soy nuevo en esto. Les dejo mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
//AQUI INSTANCIE UN OBJETO DE LA CLASE BANDA 
Banda arreglo = new Banda();
Musico[] musico = arreglo.musico;

Instrumento guitarra = new Instrumento("guitarra","cuerdas");
Musico AngusYoung = new Musico("AngusYoung","solista",guitarra);
AngusYoung.setInstrumento(guitarra);

Instrumento voz = new Instrumento("voz","viento");
Musico BrianJohnson = new Musico("BrianJohnson","vocalista",voz);
BrianJohnson.setInstrumento(voz);

Instrumento guitarraritmica = new Instrumento("guitarra ritmica","cuerdas");
Musico MalcolmYoung = new Musico("MalcolmYoung","ritmico",guitarraritmica);
MalcolmYoung.setInstrumento(guitarraritmica);

Instrumento bajo = new Instrumento("bajo","cuerdas");
Musico CliffWilliams = new Musico("CliffWilliams","bajista",bajo);
CliffWilliams.setInstrumento(bajo);

Instrumento bateria = new Instrumento("bateria","percusion");
Musico ChrisSlade = new Musico("ChrisSlade","baterista",bateria); ChrisSlade.setInstrumento(bateria);

musico[0]= AngusYoung;
musico[1]= BrianJohnson;
musico[2]= MalcolmYoung;
musico[3]= CliffWilliams;
musico[4]= ChrisSlade;
}

    public class Banda {

    Musico musico[] = new Musico[5]; //ARREGLO


    public Banda() {


    }

    public Musico[] getMusico() {
        return musico;
    }

    public void setMusico(Musico[] musico) {
        this.musico = musico;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return "Banda{" + "musico=" + musico + '}';
    }

    public class Validaciones {  //EN ESTA CLASE DEBO MANDAR A LLAMAR EL ARREGLO QUE SE LLENO EN EL MAIN

    //SUPUESTO METODO QUE RESIVE EL ARREGLO LLENO DEL MAIN
    public Musico band (Musico[] musico){

        //CREO QUE SE DEBE ASIGNAR A UNA VARIABLE PARA USARLO 

        //AQUI DEBERIA ESTAR EL IF Y EL FOR 

        return null;

    }

}
```

He investigado pero no me queda claro como manejar un arreglo como objeto en un metodo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas haciendo esta bien.

Para llamar al metodo de la clase Validaciones, solo debes instaciar un objeto de la misma

```
Validaciones v = new Validaciones ();
```

Y luego para llamar al metodo solo tienes que hacer

```
v.band(musico);
```

El problema que tiene tu codigo, es que tu clase Banda en realidad no tiene ningun musico, porque no asignaste los musicos al array dentro de esa clase, si no que los asignaste a un array propio del main.

Es mas, con la clase banda, no hiciste nada, solo la instanciaste.

Recorrer el arreglo se puede hacer con un for o un foreach, y ese es tu ejercicio ;)

Comment: Lo que está haciendo está pésimo en muchos sentidos. Su clase `Banda` es algo fijo, útil solamente para no más de 5 músicos. Lo que él expresa en la pregunta: *no me queda claro como manejar un arreglo como objeto en un metodo*  es un reflejo de ese error. Convendría explicarle **cómo recibir un array de `n` músicos en su clase `Banda`, usando a su vez la clase `Musico` para el array**... de ese modo su clase `Banda` sí tendría sentido. Creo yo que ese es el *quid*  de la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano no quise modificarle todo el codigo porque es claramente un ejercicio, y solo quise solucionar su problema actual, que es como pasarle un array a un procedimiento. Si te parece darle una explicacion mas compleja y por ahi complicarlo un poco mas bienvenido. Si te parece solamente marcarle algunos puntos, los agrego a la respuesta. Pero no parece que OP este tan avanzado todavia.